# Converting from mp4 to Xvid avi using avconv?

Tags: sound, video, conversion, avconv

I normally use avidemux to convert mp4s to Xvid AVI for my Philips Streamium SLM5500. Normally I select MPEG-4 ASP (Xvid) at Two Pass with an average bitrate f 1500kb/s for video and AC3 (lav) audio and it converts correctly.

However, I'm trying to using avconv so I can automate the process with a script, but when I do this the video stutters and stops playing part way through. I have a suspicion its something to do with a faulty audio conversion.

The commands I'm using are as follows:

```
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -pass 1 -vtag xvid -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k -b:v 1500k -f avi /dev/null
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -pass 2 -vtag xvid -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k -b:v 1500k -f avi video.avi
```

There is a bewildering array of arguments for avconv. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a way I can script avidemux from a headless server?

Please see command line output:

```
$ avconv -y -i video.mp4 -pass 1 -vtag xvid -an -b:v 1500k -f avi /dev/null
avconv version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 14:49:20 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
  Duration: 00:44:09.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 669 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x404 [PAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], 538 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 100 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: ac3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:42
[buffer @ 0x7f4c40] w:720 h:404 pixfmt:yuv420p
Output #0, avi, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x404 [PAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], q=2-31, pass 1, 1500 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg4)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=66227 fps=328 q=2.0 Lsize=       0kB time=2649.16 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:401602kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000000%
$ avconv -y -i video.mp4 -pass 2 -vtag xvid -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k -b:v 1500k -f avi video.avi
avconv version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 14:49:20 with gcc 4.7.2
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
  Duration: 00:44:09.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 669 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x404 [PAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], 538 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 100 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: ac3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:42
[buffer @ 0x12b4f00] w:720 h:404 pixfmt:yuv420p
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[mpeg4 @ 0x12b3ec0] [lavc rc] Using all of requested bitrate is not necessary for this video with these parameters.
Output #0, avi, to 'video.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x404 [PAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], q=2-31, pass 2, 1500 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:38
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: ac3, 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-04 13:53:42
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 -> ac3)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:44100 fmt:s16 ch:2 to rate:44100 fmt:flt ch:2
frame=66227 fps=284 q=2.2 Lsize=  458486kB time=2649.13 bitrate=1417.8kbits/s    
video:413716kB audio:41393kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.741969%
```

Answer (score 1):

with several pass, you should deactivate audio on pass 1, with the -an option, so :

```
avconv -y -i video.mp4 -pass 1 -vtag libxvid -an -b:v 1500k -f avi /dev/null
```

Comment: Why do I need to deactivate audio on the first pass?

Comment: That seemed to make no difference to the output.

Comment: they recommand in the man page to deactivate audio (-an) and set output to null (dev/null), but you are not forced to. please try it this way :
`avconv -y -i vid.mp4 -pass 1 -vtag xvid -b:v 1500k -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k vid1.avi` and 
`avconv -y -i vid.mp4 -pass 2 -vtag xvid -b:v 1500k -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k vid2.avi`
report your log if this doesnt work.
according to your source (format and resolution), difference in vid1 and vid2 can be quite little.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how those commands are different. I've attached a log above.

Comment: 2nd command (with `-pass 2`) uses the log file created with the 1st command (with `-pass 1`) to generate vid2. 
if you try without the `/dev/null` you can compare the vid1 and vid2 and see how they are different in quality and size of file. but for sure you will never use the the `-pass1` option without `-pass2`.
personally i don't use much this option... difference is too insignificant with a standard conversion. but it depends on your source format.
at least your log seems to show that your audio prbl is solved :)

Comment: When I try this, I get the following errors. Any suggestions?

`[avi @ 0x1a39420] Tag libx/0x7862696c incompatible with output codec id '13'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)` [Full logs here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6485422/).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Manufacturer, the Philips SLM5500 would be best combined with either [WMA or MPEG video](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/cpindex.pl?ctn=SLM5500/05&dct=QAC&faqview=1&refdisplay=DNP_SLM5500_003&refnr=0052880&scy=GB&slg=ENG).

Based on that assumption, you could easily use the following for avconv:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 1500k -c:a mp2 video.mpg
```

This should be enough to get you started, you can adjust your settings for two pass as you see fit.